# How to define array of objects data for D3 (with some missing properties) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have `data` like so. Note that it must have `YearQtr` and *at least one of* the other three keys `House`, `Unit` and `Land`:

```
const randomInt = () => Math.random() * 1000
const data = [
  { YearQtr: '2000Q1', House: randomInt(), Unit: randomInt(), Land: randomInt() },
  { YearQtr: '2000Q2',                     Unit: randomInt()                    },
  { YearQtr: '2000Q4', House: randomInt(),                    Land: randomInt() },
  { YearQtr: '2001Q2',                     Unit: randomInt(), Land: randomInt() },
  { YearQtr: '2002Q1', House: randomInt(), Unit: randomInt(),                   },
]
```

I'm trying to enforce these constrainst in TypeScript without any luck, I have tried (with errors):

TypeScript definition attempt 1:

```
type NameLabel = 'House' | 'Unit' | 'Land'
type StackbarDatum = {
    valueLabel: string
    [nameLabel in NameLabel]?: number
}
```

or
TypeScript definition attempt 2:

```
type StackbarDatum
  = { YearQtr: string, House?: number, Unit?: number, Land: number } 
  | { YearQtr: string, House?: number, Unit: number, Land?: number } 
  | { YearQtr: string, House: number, Unit?: number, Land?: number }
  | { YearQtr: string, House?: number, Unit: number, Land: number }
  | { YearQtr: string, House?: number, Unit?: number, Land: number }
  | { YearQtr: string, House?: number, Unit: number, Land?: number }
  | { YearQtr: string, House: number, Unit?: number, Land?: number }
```

I'm looking for how to define this in TypeScript, avoid the use of `any` and then be able to run the following functions:

```
function getNameLabel(data: StackbarDatum[]): string {
    return Array.from(new Set(data.map(d => Object.keys(d)).flat()))[0]
}

function getCategories(data: StackbarDatum[]): string[] {
    return Array.from(new Set(data.map(d => Object.keys(d)).flat())).slice(1)
}

function getMaxValue(data: StackbarDatum[]): any {
    let categories = getCategories(data)

    return d3Array.max(
        data.map(datum => <number>d3Array.max(
            [ d3Array.sum( categories.map( category => datum[category] )) ] 
        ))
    )
}
```

Comment: what about having all of the 3 items as optional? and ad some logic in your function?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan - in the attempt 1 above, I have defined all as optional. However my `getMaxValue` function gives me red squiggly error at `datum[category]` complaining there is no index signature with type string

Comment: if possible can you please create simple reproduction examle? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and put the link here?

Comment: Here is the link to reproduction example in typescript playground: https://tsplay.dev/Nr2Y5N